# Why "new Pushpin()" creates a reference of a previous pushpin?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1

I want to create 2 pushpins to add them in a layer in bing maps on windows phone 7 app.
I have created a function that creates a pushpin with some predefined attributes.
The odd thing is that when I create the first pin using this function the 

`Pushpin pin; 

pin = new Pushpin();` works as expected. It creates a new pushpin...
But when this functions works for the second pushpin the above code creates a reference to the first push pin... 
Why?

The code i use is the bellow

```
Pushpin pin0 = createDefaultPushpin(38.0, 23.0, "test0");
Pushpin pin1 = createDefaultPushpin(39.0, 24.0, "test1");


private Pushpin createDefaultPushpin(double lat, double lon, String name)
        {
            Pushpin pin;
            pin = new Pushpin();


            pin.Location.Latitude = lat;
            pin.Location.Longitude = lon;
            pin.Location.Altitude = 0;
            pin.Name = name;

            ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
            st.ScaleX = 0.25;
            st.ScaleY = 0.25;
            st.CenterX = 0;
            st.CenterY = 60;

            pin.RenderTransform = st;
            pin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            return pin;
        }
```

Comment: How do you know that this code creates a reference to the first pushpin? How did you observe that the references were the same?

Comment: Unless there's some code elsewhere doing some amount of wizardry, what you're telling us is impossible.

Comment: @MarkByers Because the two pushpins are in the same position And I have run the new Pushpin() while in the function in the watch while debugging and this returned the first pushpin...

Comment: @Peter: Two pushpins being in the same position doesn't mean they are the same reference. It could also be two different objects that have the same values. Or the values could be declared static. Or a few other scenarios.

Comment: @MarkByers Unfortunately this is not the case. The "new Pushpin()" in the watch while debugging references the same pin with the first...

Comment: @Peter: Again, I have to ask you what evidence do you have that they are the same reference? I don't think that the Visual Studio debugger shows this information. If you run the code `object.ReferenceEquals(pin1, pin2)` what is the result?

Comment: @MarkByers Not surprisingly you are right. It is false. But why then this create a new object of pushpins and gives the values of the first one?

Comment: @Peter: My first guess would be that you've declared something static when it shouldn't have been. Can you post the class definition of Pushpin?

Comment: @MarkByers Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Pushpin. I have not declared any static. The only thing that this does is that when i run this code the values of pin0 are equal to pin1. if a add a pushpin pin2 with the same function then the values of pin0 = pin1 = pin2. pin 2 wins..

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see any error in your code... I don't think I can help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with colleagues, it turned out that the class Pushpin has a dependency property attached to location. That is why it behaves like that.
The solution is to do the following.

```
Pushpin pin = new Pushpin(){
                  Location = new Location(){
                      Latitude = lat,Longitude = lon, Altitude = 0
                  }
              };
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with dependency properties. It has to do with the Location object being shared. So I believe my intuition was right in my answer above, though I was misled by this web page to think that there was a three-arg constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.location.location.aspx

Comment: @CoreyKosak This is what I 'm saying. The Location is shared through the dependency it has. But this happens only when i use new Pushpin inside the function. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: You are not using .NET terminology properly. The term "DependencyProperty" refers to the property technology introduced by Microsoft with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). A dependency property is not a simple CLR proeprty. Just because this property appears to "depend" on another, you ought not call it a DependencyProperty. You may wish to read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've never used these classes or this platform, but let's accept everything that you've said above as fact. Then I think the culprit must be that the "Location" object is being inadvertently shared between your three Pushpins. (I think it's pretty irresponsible of the Pushpin constructor to do so, but again, I'm just going from the evidence you've provided, not my own experience)

Can you try

```
pin.Location=new Location(lat, lon, 0);
```

at the appropriate place in the code above, and tell us what happens?

Comment: Location does not have this type of constructor. Therefore I cannot use this.